# No disks visible behind SAS Expander

Tags: linux, sas, hba

I'm trying to hook up an Infortrend SAS shelf and I have a big issues to get the disks visible.
The shelf is connected via a LSI Logic SAS1068E B3 HBA with current IT firmware, and 2 SAS cables.

The card is recognized by kernel and until this point it looks quite okay
Unfortunately only the expanders inside the shelf are visible for the controller and not the disks attached to it (16x2TB) - The are missing in the Bios menu and LSI Util/booted system.

Did anyone had some issues like that before and can point my into any direction?

**LSI Util Output**

```
LSI Logic MPT Configuration Utility, Version 1.62, January 14, 2009

1 MPT Port found

     Port Name         Chip Vendor/Type/Rev    MPT Rev  Firmware Rev  IOC
 1.  /proc/mpt/ioc0    LSI Logic SAS1068E B3     105      01210000     0

Select a device:  [1-1 or 0 to quit] 1

 1.  Identify firmware, BIOS, and/or FCode
 2.  Download firmware (update the FLASH)
 4.  Download/erase BIOS and/or FCode (update the FLASH)
 8.  Scan for devices
10.  Change IOC settings (interrupt coalescing)
13.  Change SAS IO Unit settings
16.  Display attached devices
20.  Diagnostics
21.  RAID actions
22.  Reset bus
23.  Reset target
42.  Display operating system names for devices
45.  Concatenate SAS firmware and NVDATA files
59.  Dump PCI config space
60.  Show non-default settings
61.  Restore default settings
66.  Show SAS discovery errors
69.  Show board manufacturing information
97.  Reset SAS link, HARD RESET
98.  Reset SAS link
99.  Reset port
 e   Enable expert mode in menus
 p   Enable paged mode
 w   Enable logging

Main menu, select an option:  [1-99 or e/p/w or 0 to quit] 8

SAS1068E's links are 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G, 3.0 G

 B___T___L  Type       Vendor   Product          Rev      SASAddress     PhyNum
 0  13   0  EnclServ   IFT      S16S-J1000       113A  500d0234003a74f1    24
 0  14   0  EnclServ   IFT      S16S-J1000       113A  500d0234003a748d    24
```

**SCSI Ouput**

```
lsscsi -Ht
[0]    megaraid_sas  
[1]    qla2xxx       fc:0x2100001b3292a0e60x000000
[2]    qla2xxx       fc:0x2101001b32b2a0e60x000000
[3]    mptsas        sas:0x500605b0014dfdf0

lsscsi -s 3
[3:0:0:0]    enclosu IFT      S16S-J1000       113A  -               -
[3:0:1:0]    enclosu IFT      S16S-J1000       113A  -               -

smp_discover /dev/bsg/expander-3\:0 
  phy  16:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf0:00  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  17:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf0:01  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  18:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf0:02  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  19:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf0:03  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  24:D:attached:[500d0234003a74f1:00  V i(SSP) t(SSP)]  3 Gbps

smp_discover /dev/bsg/expander-3\:1
  phy  16:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf4:04  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  17:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf4:05  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  18:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf4:06  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  19:T:attached:[500605b0014dfdf4:07  i(SSP+STP+SMP)]  3 Gbps
  phy  24:D:attached:[500d0234003a748d:00  V i(SSP) t(SSP)]  3 Gbps
```

**SAS Controller**

```
./sasflash -c 1 -list

 ****************************************************************************
    LSI Corporation SAS FLASH Utility.

    SASFlash Version 1.30.00.00 (2011.08.24) 

    Copyright (c) 2006-2011 LSI Corporation. All rights reserved.
 ****************************************************************************

        Adapter Selected is a LSI SAS 1068E(B3):

Controller Number:              1
Controller:                     1068E(B3)
PCI Address:                    00:07:00:00
SAS Address:                    500605b-0-014d-fdf0
NVDATA Version (Default):       0x2d03
NVDATA Version (Persistent):    0x2d83
Product ID:                     0x2204
Firmware Version:               01.33.00.00
NVDATA Vendor:                  LSILogic
NVDATA Product ID:              SAS3081E
BIOS Version:                   06.36.00.00
BIOS Alternate Version:         N/A
EFI BSD Version:                N/A
FCODE Version:                  N/A

Finished Processing Commands Successfully.
        Exiting SASFlash.
```

Answer (score 0):

After messing around with this topic a couple days I figured out, that it's probably not possible to use this shelf as JBOD without putting some serious investment into reverse engineering. 
Even though you'll get to see the SAS expanders, theres no way to reach the disks

The datasheet from Infortrend describes this shelf as **"Proprietary enclosure service via in-band methodology"** - so without investing the proprietary part it seem like its not supposed to be directly attached to a server.